# Display archive date on landing page

Tags: category-archive

I'm trying to display the category archive date on the landing page after the archive date is clicked in sidebar.

Here's my sidebar with category and archive links:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Categories</h4>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="blog"}
        <a href="{path='blog/index'}">{category_name}</a><br />
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Archives</h4>
    <ul>
    {exp:channel:month_links channel="blog" limit="50"}
        <li><a href="{path='blog/index'}">{month}, {year}</a></li>
    {/exp:channel:month_links}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the `{exp:channel:category_heading}` on the `blog/index` landing page and that displays category heading just fine, but can't figure out how to do the same for the archive date.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I used [DT Plugin](https://github.com/jjpmann/ee-dt) and pulled in segment variables and seems to work fine.

{exp:dt set="{segment_3}/00/{segment_2}" format="%F, %Y" ee_format="true" month="1"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EE3 you could try this plugin - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin - I've not tested it but the docs suggest you should be able to get a nice date output from it.

You could always just grab the segment values in your page heading, eg

```
<h1>Archive for {segment_3}/{segment_2}</h1>
```

Comment: A bit hacky, but ya, that should work. I updated my answer above with specific code used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your month archive URL's are in format blog/[year]/[month] you could. use Low's Nice date plugin to grab the segment values and output a date in whatever format you need. http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date

Comment: Is there not a way to do this out of the box in EE?

Comment: I should also clarify I'm on EE3...the addon recommended is only compatible with EE1 and EE2.